# How to migrate from Jboss 5.x to Jboss 7.x if application uses WorkManager API

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jca, workmanagers

We are working to migrate an existing application in production environment that in some case use WorkManager (as vertical scalability) to parallelize the workload.

The application uses also JMS but due to performance issue some part are implemented using **JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor** [Spring 3.1], in order to share the same JVM memory for all threads running and to avoid to open native threads in Java EE environment.

I read a lot of others discussion about this topic and the reason because WorkManager API are not available on Jboss 7.x, such as:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/169380

https://community.jboss.org/message/718053

But sincerely we don't understand how can me migrate (**in very fast way**) the application from Jboss 5.x to Jboss 7.x (Jboss EAP 5 to Jboss EAP 6) without impact on source code (or just very small impact).

If I understand right there is just a way to implement a JCA resource adapter to use workmanager because workmanager is not available via JMX. is it right?

I think there aren't no chances to introduce commonj, due to the reason explained above.

At the moment we can't rewrite the source code and we would like to avoid to open native threads to solve the situation in very shot time.

Did someone solve this issue? Has someone an implementation of JCA resource adapter that uses WorkManager as in previous versions of Jboss?

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes you could share it here and accept your answer.